# Enter a Failed Docker Container with a Different Command

Tags: linux, bash, docker, chef

I have a fairly complicated docker container I'm attempting to build. As part of the build process I have I install Chef and have Chef install a number of cookbooks using Chef-Solo. I am having the cookbooks fail a certain point and need to inspect the container's file structure in order to fix the problem.

Is there a way to enter an Exited container to examine error logs and the like?

I can't `docker start fa3ecc46bc72`  as the container will exit immediately as the Command is `/bin/sh -c 'chef-so..` so I can't `docker exec -it fa3ecc46bc72 bash` like one normally would.

Is there anyway around this without running the container and installing stuff manually to see where it fails?